# IOS Google maps marker title doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've used ios google maps sdk, I need to display title when zoomed in to a certain level same like gooogle maps. But right now its not working at all.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, markerFor object: Any) -> GMSMarker? {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        if let poItem = object as? POIItem {
            let customMarker = CustomMarker.loadNib()
            customMarker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 50)
            marker.iconView = customMarker
            marker.title = poItem.name
        }
        return marker
    }
```

I'm returning my marker in renderer but title is not appearing. Please help me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The marker title will be shown once you click on it, i.e when the marker is selected. To select a marker programmatically when zoomed in, use this `mapView?.selectedMarker = marker`

Comment: But in google maps titles appears automatically when zoomed. When tapped or selected it's totally different case.